# javascript/react keydown vs onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a weird interaction happening on my javascript calculator. As far as I can tell, my keydown event and my onClick should be doing the same thing. However the outcome is different.

A live version of the calculator is here: https://aaronrbetts.github.io/Calculator/

if i click: '7+' the output shows 7+.

if i use the numPad and type '7+' i get '14+'.

```
  handleKeyPress(e) {
// Check if key pressed is in calc buttons array
var result = buttonObjects.find(obj => {
  return obj.keyCode === e.keyCode
});

if(result) {
  // handle input if key pressed is on calculator
  this.handleInput(result.value, result.type);
}
```

}

```
  render() {
document.addEventListener("keydown", this.handleKeyPress)

      {buttonObjects.map((key, idx) => (
        <button key={idx} id={key.id} onClick={() => this.handleInput(key.value, key.type)}>{key.value}</button>
      ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

`addEventListener` is called in `render`, so every time your component rerenders, `handleKeyPress` will run an additional time when a key is held down. To solve this, move this call to `componentDidMount`.

Comment: I moved the event listener to componentDidMount but I'm still getting the same issue

Comment: Did you also remove it from `render`?